# Elliptic Curve Cryptography Public Key Algorithm of the x509 certificate in the certificate chain is not supported?

Tags: azure, x509certificate, azure-keyvault

I am getting this error when I am trying to import a certificate from my machine provided by another CA (Honeywell CA).

CSR was created using the private key created by command - `openssl ecparam -genkey -name prime256v1 | openssl ec -out webtls.key -aes128`

For import, I tried azure UI, Azure powershell, and azureCLI nothing worked got the same error.

Any idea about this?

Comment: Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificate-scenarios

Comment: already followed, Steps are verified and correct certificated is generated with the supported key but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ECC certificate needs to be created in a very specific manner.  I spoke with the Key Vault product team about this specific issue and ended up with an ECC FAQ. It's a detailed operation that requires a special configuration file when the cert is being generated.  I'm not going to go into the complete detail as I have it documented on my blog post:

https://azidentity.azurewebsites.net/post/2019/05/24/ecc-certificates-in-the-key-vault

Comment: yes we can do this using the same steps suggested by you. but In this case my private key will be outside the key-vault. I want to create pub-private key pair inside the vault and raising the csr to my own choice CA, once I received the pem file from CA , Merge that Inside the vault with private key to complete the certificate.

Comment: I am able to do so but only on problem is there When I am using Signasync method I am not able to verify the signatures using extracted public key from vault. Only verifyasync method is working but i need to check using public key for offline use